# Websites using the Facebook graph api are loading very slow

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a few websites that have a custom Facebook feed which I load in using the Graph API.

In the past everything loaded very quick but since about a week or two all sites stop loading at the feed part and only finishes loading completely after 30 seconds or more.

What can be the cause of this?

I am sure it is the Facebook feed because when I remove it the site loads quickly again.

Below is an example feed from a website which has this issue:

```
$json_object = file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/thepagesid/posts?fields=full_picture%2Cmessage%2Cstory%2Cpermalink_url%2Cupdated_time%2Cfrom&access_token=mytoken");

$feedarray = json_decode($json_object);

$f = 0;

foreach ( $feedarray->data as $key => $feed_data )
{

if($feed_data->full_picture != ''){
  $fbimage = $feed_data->full_picture;
}else{
  $fbimage = 'assets/images/fbnoimg.jpg';
}

$shortstrfb = substr($feed_data->message, 0, 170) . '...';
if($feed_data->message != ''){
  $f++;
}

if($f > 4){
  break;
}

if($feed_data->message != '' && $feed_data->from->name == 'facebook page name'){
      $facebookfeed .= '

      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
          <div class="single-product-wrap fbwrapdiv">
              <div class="product-image">
                  <a href="'.$feed_data->permalink_url.'" target="_blank">
                  <span class="datefb">'.date("d-m-Y",strtotime($feed_data->updated_time)).'</span>
                  <img class="fbimgclass" src="'.$fbimage.'" alt=""></a>
                  <div class="product-action">
                      <a href="'.$feed_data->permalink_url.'" target="_blank" class="wishlist"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="product-content">
                  <div class="price-box">
                      <p class="facebooktext">'.$shortstrfb.'</p>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>';
    }
}
echo $facebookfeed;
```

Comment: Making a new API request on every single page load is not a clever thing to do. You should cache this data on your end somehow.

Comment: also, i would use curl instead of file_get_contents.

Comment: @luschn Thank you, this fixed it for me. Now everything loads fast again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by using curl.

I replaced:

```
$json_object = file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/thepagesid/posts?fields=full_picture%2Cmessage%2Cstory%2Cpermalink_url%2Cupdated_time%2Cfrom&access_token=mytoken");

$feedarray = json_decode($json_object);
```

With:

```
$graph_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/thepagesid/posts?fields=full_picture%2Cmessage%2Cstory%2Cpermalink_url%2Cupdated_time%2Cfrom&access_token=mytoken';
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $graph_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

$output = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

$feedarray = json_decode($output);
```

Comment: that´s just the optimization for speed, but you REALLY need to cache this instead of calling the api on every page it, as 04FS suggested. API calls take time even with curl, and there are api limits.